# How to solve CROSS Origin issue in ionic-vue?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic-vue

I am new to Ionic framework (with Vuejs) and trying to make simple Crud app. But due to CORS issues, i can't able to login.

Browser console show XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localproject.test/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy

I tried a lot of different solutions, without success  Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your code here? or your api call code?

Answer (score 0):

You will allow CORS from your backend. If you want to resolve CORS issue from your end you will use ionic HTTP native plugin [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http). This is not recommended because you can't track requests from your network tab.

my suggestion you need to resolve your CORS issue from your backend.

Comment: Okay. Thanks brother, It would be great if i can do this from front end side as i have fix it with core vue versions, But Ionic not allowing cross.

Comment: You need to use Ionic http plugin which i provide link.

Answer (score 0):

If your app will be running on browser, use **Proxy server**.

Example: I want to post to http://localproject.test/api/login.

In `package.json`, I will add this line:

`"proxy": "http://localproject.test/api"`

My POST request in Login component:

```
     axios
          .post("/login", loginData)
          .then((response) => {
           ...
            }
            return response.data;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            ...
          });
```